# How to average 7 years of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, lubridate, reshape2

I'm new to R programming and this website so please bear with my incompetence. I pulled atmospheric data from the past 7 years for 7 variables; ozone, CO, NO, NO2, windspeed, PM 2.5, PM 10. What I am trying to do is graph this data to see if the government mandated stay at home orders  during this covid-19 pandemic had any effect on atmospheric composition. From the graph I'm not quite sure what to do next. I believe I need an average of the past 7 years? The data is hourly data displayed in a 24 hour format.

**NO.dat data frame**

```
dput(head(NO.dat,10))
structure(list(Date = c("3/1/2014", "3/2/2014", "3/3/2014", "3/4/2014",
"3/5/2014", "3/6/2014", "3/7/2014", "3/8/2014", "3/9/2014", "3/10/2014"
), X0.00 = c(3.6, NA, 2.3, 17.1, 0.4, 0.9, 110.9, 0.1, NA, 0.4
), X1.00 = c(6.3, NA, 1.4, 18.7, 0.2, 0.2, 15.8, 0, NA, 0.6),
X2.00 = c(2.3, 0.6, 0.4, 13.9, 0.2, 0.1, 13.5, 0, 0.8, 0.3
), X3.00 = c(0.9, 0.3, 0.9, 4.2, 0.5, 0.3, 22.7, 0.2, 0.5,
0.7), X4.00 = c(0.2, 0.1, 2.8, 5.2, 0.7, 0, 40.1, 0.1, 0.8,
2.8), X5.00 = c(0.4, 0, 4.4, 11.1, 2.4, 1.8, 22.2, 0.1, 0.8,
4.1), X6.00 = c(11.8, 0.1, 17.6, 51.8, 3.6, 8.2, 2.8, 0.3,
1, 20.1), X7.00 = c(39.5, 0.6, 30.3, 118.6, 15.7, 12, 3.7,
1, 1.9, 39.1), X8.00 = c(23.9, 0.7, 25.8, 35.6, 20.6, 11.4,
6.3, 1.5, 1.2, 33.5), X9.00 = c(8.4, 1.1, 20.8, 28.7, 5.1,
9.4, 3.7, 1.3, 0.8, 9.6), X10.00 = c(4.3, 0.5, 13.3, 17.1, 
1.1, 6, 1.3, 2.4, 1.4, 2.5), X11.00 = c(3.9, 0.3, 8.3, 13.9, 
0.5, 5.6, 0.9, 2.3, 1.3, 1.2), X12.00 = c(4.1, 0.6, 6.3, 
12.2, 0.6, 4.3, 0.8, 1.6, 1, 1.1), X13.00 = c(2.6, 0.6, 9.1, 
9, 0.6, 3.6, 0.7, 2, 1.6, 1.1), X14.00 = c(3.7, 0.5, 9.3, 
1.4, 0.9, 2.3, 0.9, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3), X15.00 = c(3.4, 0.5, 
9.4, 0.8, 0.8, 1.8, 1.2, 1.8, 1.2, 1.1), X16.00 = c(1, 0.3, 
5.7, 0.6, 2.5, 2.3, 1.1, 2.3, 1.2, 1), X17.00 = c(0.9, 0.3, 
13.4, 0.5, 3.2, 1.8, 0.7, 1.4, 0.6, 0.7), X18.00 = c(0.8, 
0.2, 22.1, 0.5, 3.9, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 0.4, 0.5), X19.00 = c(0.5, 
0.2, 24.2, 1.8, 15.4, 1.1, 0.1, 0.8, 10.1, 0.6), X20.00 = c(0.5, 
1, 18.4, 17.1, 5.1, 33.4, 0.3, 0.1, 45.3, 0.5), X21.00 = c(1, 
0.5, 15.4, 55.7, 2, 39.5, 4.1, 0, 49.5, 0.4), X22.00 = c(0.4, 
0.2, 8.1, 52.6, 2.7, 25.2, 0.9, 0.3, 27.2, 0.5), X23.00 = c(0.4, 
6, 11.9, 2.2, 2.5, 62.1, 0.2, 0.1, 3.3, 0.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**NO2.dat data frame**

```
dput(head(NO2.dat,10))
structure(list(Date = c("3/1/2014", "3/2/2014", "3/3/2014", "3/4/2014", 
"3/5/2014", "3/6/2014", "3/7/2014", "3/8/2014", "3/9/2014", "3/10/2014"
), X0.00 = c(5, 0.5, 3.2, 16.3, 0.4, 2, 91.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2),
X1.00 = c(7, 0.4, 2.4, 18.4, 0.3, 0.6, 17.7, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1
), X2.00 = c(1.7, 0.4, 0.3, 16.3, 0.1, 0.4, 10.3, 0.3, 0.6, 
0.2), X3.00 = c(0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 4.4, 0.8, 0.6, 8.5, 0.4, 0.5, 
0.6), X4.00 = c(0.6, 0.2, 2.6, 4.4, 1, 0.6, 43.7, 0.3, 0.7, 
2.6), X5.00 = c(0.6, 0.3, 5, 12.8, 2.7, 2.8, 15.7, 0.4, 0.7, 
4.3), X6.00 = c(5.8, 0.4, 18.6, 60.5, 3.8, 9.5, 3, 0.6, 0.9, 
22.1), X7.00 = c(32, 0.7, 27.4, 117.5, 15.3, 12.6, 4.4, 1.7, 
2.2, 36.2), X8.00 = c(21.3, 1, 22.7, 37.1, 20.3, 12.5, 7.6, 
2.1, 1.4, 33.2), X9.00 = c(7.9, 1.4, 19.4, 28.7, 5, 10.5, 
4.8, 2.3, 0.9, 11), X10.00 = c(4.2, 0.6, 12.4, 19, 1.6, 8.1, 
1.9, 3.1, 1.8, 2.9), X11.00 = c(4.2, 0.8, 9.6, 15.7, 1.1, 
7.4, 1.6, 3.4, 1.8, 1), X12.00 = c(4.2, 0.9, 6.6, 14.2, 1.2, 
6.1, 1.4, 2.7, 1.3, 1.2), X13.00 = c(NA, 0.8, 9.4, NA, 1.4, 
3.9, 1.2, NA, 1.9, 1.2), X14.00 = c(NA, 0.9, 9.6, NA, 1.9, 
3.1, 1.3, NA, 1.3, 1.3), X15.00 = c(NA, 0.9, 9.6, NA, 1.7, 
2.9, 1.9, NA, 1.6, 1), X16.00 = c(1, 0.8, 6.4, 1.2, 3.8, 
3, 1.8, 3, 1.2, 1.1), X17.00 = c(1.2, 0.7, 12, 1, 4, 1.5, 
1.5, 2, 0.5, 0.6), X18.00 = c(0.9, 0.5, 20.2, 0.9, 5, 1, 
1.3, 1.5, 0.3, 0.3), X19.00 = c(0.5, 0.5, 19.1, 2.1, 15.8, 
1.1, 0.6, 1.3, 5.1, 0.4), X20.00 = c(0.4, 1.1, 17.5, 7, 4.2, 
24.9, 0.5, 0.7, 32.1, 0.4), X21.00 = c(0.7, 0.7, 13.3, 28.4, 
2.4, 31.7, 3.4, 0.7, 37, 0.3), X22.00 = c(0.4, 0.4, 7.3, 
21, 2.9, 18.5, 1.2, 0.6, 20, 0.3), X23.00 = c(0.4, 5.8, 11.6, 
0.8, 2.9, 47.8, 0.5, 0.6, 2.1, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
'''

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

#remove summary stats
NO.dat <- NO.dat[,1:25]
NO2.dat <- NO2.dat[,1:25]

#reorganize data using reshape
x<-melt(NO.dat, id="Date")
colnames(x) <- c("Date","Hour","NO")
x$Hour<- as.numeric(x$Hour)-y<-melt(NO2.dat, id="Date")
y<-melt(NO2.dat, id="Date")
colnames(y) <- c("Date","Hour","NO2")
y$Hour<- as.numeric(y$Hour)-1

x <- cbind(x,y$NO2)
colnames(x)[4] <- "NO2"
x$min <- ":00"
x$time <- paste(x$Hour, x$min, sep="")
x$DT <- paste(x$Date, x$time)
x %>% select(DT, NO, NO2) %>% mutate(NOx=NO + NO2) %>% mutate(DT =       
mdy_hm(DT)) %>% arrange(DT) -> x

p <- ggplot(x, aes(x=DT, y=NOx)) + geom_line() + xlab("")

x$index <- 1:nrow(x)
loessMod10 <- loess(NOx ~ index, data=x, span=0.10, na.action=)
x <- na.omit(x)
x$smoothed10 <- predict(loessMod10)

#pdf("El Paso NOx.pdf",w=6,h=3,useDingbats= FALSE)
p <- ggplot(x) + geom_line(aes(x=DT, y=NOx), linetype = "dashed", 
size=0.3) + xlab("") +
geom_line(aes(x=DT, y=smoothed10), color = "red") + labs(y="NOx 
(ppbv)") +
ggtitle("NOx concentrations at Chamizal TCEQ Site") + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
annotate("text",x=as.POSIXct("2020-03-24 17:00:00"), y=130, +
label="Stay Home 1", angle=90, size=2.5) 
 annotate("text",x=as.POSIXct("2020-04-01 17:00:00"), y=130, 
label="Stay Home 2", angle=90, size = 2.5) +
annotate("segment", x = as.POSIXct("2020-03-24 17:00:00"), xend= 
as.POSIXct("2020-03-24 17:00:00"), y = 0, yend = 105, colour = 
"blue") +
annotate("segment", x = as.POSIXct("2020-04-01 17:00:00"), xend= 
as.POSIXct("2020-04-01 17:00:00"), y = 0, yend = 105, colour = 
"blue")
```

'''
[Graph that I think needs to be averaged??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cczm0.png)

Comment: please have a look at the openair package and its beautiful manual, possibly one of the best package for dealing with air quality data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add a `year` column and use this to group your data by year. You could then overlay the data by year.

For fun, I had a go at reproducing the plots avoiding reshape.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

# stack raw data for NO and NO2
NO_stacked <- NO %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X"),
               names_to = "hours",
               values_to = "NO") 
NO2_stacked <- NO2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X"),
               names_to = "hours",
               values_to = "NO2")

# combine into one data frame
data <- bind_cols(NO_stacked, NO2_stacked) %>%
  select(Date, hours, NO, NO2)

# coerce dates to POSIXct and add hours; remove hours; reshape to long format using pivot_longer
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y", tz = "UTC"),
         hours = as.numeric(str_sub(hours, start = 2, end = -1))) %>%
  mutate(Date = Date + 60*60*hours) %>%
  select(-hours) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("NO"),
               names_to = "Contaminant",
               values_to = "Concentration")

# plot
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Date, y = Concentration)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Contaminant), nrow = 2) +
  ggtitle("NOx concentrations at Chamizal TCEQ Site")
```

[image]

Comment: I keep receiving an error saying that it cannot subset columns that don't exist. x Column 'Date' doesn't exist. However 'Date' does exist when I use the print function for the stacked NO and NO2 data.

Comment: Can you check for any typo's? I routinely mistype `data` and `date`. Otherwise, please share your code.

Comment: No typos, just copied it basically how you had it, it would not select the columns of which i had commanded giving me that the column does not exist           NO_stacked <- NO.dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X"),
               names_to = "hours",
               values_to = "NO")
NO2_stacked <- NO2.dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X"),
               names_to = "hours",
               values_to = "NO2")
data <- bind_cols(NO_stacked, NO2_stacked) %>%
  select(Date, hours, NO, NO2)

Comment: I did not include the csv data file code that my data is in in the above comment. But when I perform the print function, I can see that those are clearly the names of my columns.

Comment: Hi `clestat`, your code runs without any issues at my end.

Comment: Hi, After running the code to make the new data frame with the stacked, it states New names were created being; Date -> Date...1, Max -> Max...2, SH -> SH...3 and so on, and when I run the next line of code selecting the Date, hours, NO, and NO2 it says that those columns don't exist. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong if the code works on your end. Please forgive my ignorance of programming, I have very little training in this.

Comment: For some reason `bind_cols` creates unique column names it appears. I thought that the function silently drops duplicate columns. In any case, you could try: `data <- bind_cols(NO_stacked, NO2_stacked %>% select(NO2)) %>%  select(Date, hours, NO, NO2)` instead, which should avoid the duplicate names as you only bind the `NO2` column.